# How to save the PDF file into Magento root folder

Tags: pdf, save, directory

```
 $pdf = Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_invoice')->getPdf($invoicesSet);
                $this->_prepareDownloadResponse('invoice'.Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s').
'.pdf', $pdf->render(), 'application/pdf');
```

I am trying to download all invoice in PDF and need to Save in Magento root folder.

But it's downloading in browser only.

Can any one help for this issue.

Comment: Please don't save it into the root folder as pdfs in the root folder would be downloadable.

Comment: Thanks for valuable reply, Can you please provide any way for "How can i download the PDF file in to magento root folder ?"

Answer (score 5):

This

```
 $this->_prepareDownloadResponse('invoice'.Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s'). '.pdf', $pdf->render(), 'application/pdf');
```

would send it to the browser. The below would write to a file in the var directory instead:

```
$name = 'invoice'.Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s'). '.pdf';
file_put_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('var').DS.$name,$pdf->render());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this method

```
$pdf->save(Mage::getBaseDir('var'). DS . 'tmpfolder' . DS 'filename.pdf');
```

This will save a local copy, just be aware folder permissions.

Greetings